What are the symmetric Laurent Polynomials?
Let $n\geq1$ and $k$ a field (can take $\Bbb C$ for simplicity). The symmetric group $S_n$ acts on the polynomial ring $k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$ via permutation of the variables. It is a classic result that the ring of invariants, i.e. symmetric polynomials, is a polynomial ring in the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_1,\dots,e_n$ occuring as the coefficients of $\prod_{i=1}^n(T-T_i)$. Suppose instead we look at the ring of Laurent polynomials $k[T_1^{\pm1},\dots,T_n^{\pm1}]$. Is there again a simple description of the ring of invariants? For example we clearly have $$k[e_1,\dots,e_n,e(T_1^{-1},\dots,T_n^{-1}), \dots, e_n(T_1^{-1},\dots,T_n^{-1})]\subseteq  k[T_1^{\pm1},\dots,T_n^{\pm1}]^{S_n}.$$
Is this an equality?
For context I was reading on the Satake isomorphism which in the $\operatorname{GL}_n$ case identifies the spherical Hecke algebra with this ring of symmetric Laurent polynomials, so I was wondering if there is an explicit description of the latter.
I suppose one can also interpret this geometrically as the quotient of the affine $n$-space minus the coordinate axis by the action given by permuting the coordinates.
There are different ways to prove $k[T_1,\dots, T_n]^{S_n}=k[e_1,\dots,e_n]$. It would be natural to see whether they work here as well. For example we know that $k[T_1^{\pm1},\dots,T_n^{\pm1}]^{S_n}$ is integrally closed and its fraction field is $k(e_1,\dots,e_n)=k(T_1,\dots,T_n)^{S_n}$ by Galois theory, so it suffices to identify the integral closure of $k[e_1,\dots,e_n,e(T_1^{-1},\dots,T_n^{-1}), \dots, e_n(T_1^{-1},\dots,T_n^{-1})]$.

Please do not answer in the comments.

If $f$ is a symmetric Laurent polynomial, then there is some positive integer $k$ such that $(t_1 \dots t_n)^k f$ is an ordinary symmetric polynomial, so $(t_1 \dots t_n)^k f \in k[e_1, \dots e_n]$. So the symmetric Laurent polynomials are given by the single localization
$$k[e_1, \dots e_n][e_n^{-1}].$$
It is not necessary to use any of the other $e_i(t_1^{-1}, \dots e_n^{-1})$, and in fact we have
$$e_i(t_1^{-1}, \dots t_n^{-1}) = e_{n-i}(t_1, \dots t_n) e_n^{-1}.$$
